# How to update file if new record comes using linux command?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

1st is src file and 2nd is lkp file. I have to update src file based on the record of lkp file and also populate the unmatched records.

Example:

src file:

```
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    100|     QC|
|    105|     XY|
|    110|     NM|
|    115|     AB|
+-------+-------+
```

lkp file:

```
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    100|     QZ|
|    105|     XY|
|    106|     XZ|
+-------+-------+
```

I have written one linux command which is returning unmatched record correctly but not updating the src file. Can you please help me what changes I need to do in linux command?

command:

```
def get_col_index(file,col):
    header=open(file, encoding="utf-8-sig").readline().strip()
    print(header)
    header_list = header.split('\001')
    print(header_list)
    print(str(header_list.index(col)+1))
    return str(header_list.index(col)+1)

matcher_string = 'awk -F \'\001\' \'NR==FNR && NR>1{id[toupper($' + get_col_index(lkp_file,call_id) + ')]; next} !(toupper($' + get_col_index(src_file,call_id) + ') in id)\' '+lkp_file+' '+src_file+'|tail -n +2 >> '+trgt_file

os.system(matcher_string)
```

Expected Output:

src file:

```
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    100|     QZ|
|    105|     XY|
|    110|     NM|
|    115|     AB|
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: so u don't want 106 in the output ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto No sir. 110 & 115 will populate as unmatched records because these are not in lkp file but 100 is there in lkp with the value QZ so this should replace in src file.

Comment: The above command is giving unmatched records only but not updating the value in src file.

Comment: That function is not bash, looks like python...

Comment: @Nic3500 see the matcher_string  line